# How to convert the string into Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I have string as `[arun, joseph, sachin, kavin]`. I want to replace this text as  `["arun", "joseph", "sachin", "kavin"]`. All the values should be in double quotes. 
    I have tried to do this using replace method. But i could not accomplish. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Do you want quotes as part of each each string, or did you say you want quotes just highlight that each part should be its own string? It would be good if you provided a clear example input / output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to turn a string containing

```
[arun, joseph, sachin, kavin]
```

into this string

```
["arun", "joseph", "sachin", "kavin"]
```

or do you want to turn it into an actual array containing `"arun"`, `"joseph"`, `"sachin"` and `"kavin"`?

Regardless, this is pretty basic string manipulation. Here's what I suggest you try:

- Use [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to get rid of the first and last character.
- Use [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the string on `", "`.
- If you want to add `'"'` before and after each component in this array, you can do

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      array[i] = '"' + array[i] + '"';
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this,

- replace `[`, `]` with an empty string.
- Then do splitting according to the comma.

  ```
  Strings parts[] = string.replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "").split("\\s*,\\s*");
  ```
- `^\\[|\\]$` matches the `[`, `]` present at the start and at the end.
- replaceAll function then replaces the matched brackets with an empty string.
- Then by splitting the resultant string according to

`\s*` -> zero or more spaces

`,`  -> comma

`\s*` -> zero or more spaces

will give you the desired output.

Comment: You might want to put anchors `^` and `$` on that expression. (And explain what it does.)